# How can I import data file from local, and to build an image with data use mongodb

Tags: mongodb, image, docker, dockerfile

Now I built an image(userdb) with the usersInfo.js data file by the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo
COPY usersInfo.js /data/db
COPY script.sh .
RUN chmod +x script.sh 
CMD [ "./script.sh"]
```

and the script.sh file as:

```
$ mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --db users --collection usersInfo --drop 
    --file /data/db/usersInfo.js
```

when I run the container as:

> docker run --name test -it userdb

it gives me the warn:

> 2017-11-10T23:14:39.781+0000   [........................] 
>   users.usersInfo 0B/10.9KB (0.0%)
>
> 2017-11-10T23:14:40.286+0000   [........................] 
>   users.usersInfo 0B/10.9KB (0.0%)
>
> 2017-11-10T23:14:40.286+0000   Failed: error connecting to db server: 
>   no reachable servers

And I run the server on the local computer, it still not works.

What I am trying to do is to import the usersInfo.js file from the image (userdb)itself, why does it ask me to connect the server here? How to fix it?

Comment: What is `users.js`? The `mongoimport` utility works with JSON files and NOT "scripts" which the `.js` extension implies. It's also a pretty bad idea to put that in the same location as where the general database files are. It's also not really clear what you are asking here. MongoDB is a "database", which means it's actually meant to "persist" the data which you load into it. If your "docker container" is not maintaining "state" of the filesystem within it, then the actual intention is to "mount" a persisted filesystem where the data files are. Hence "you don't need to load on each startup"

Comment: And it "asks you to connect to the server" because no server is currently running at the time of invocation and the utility actually requires one to be running. So you would actually need to "await" the startup of the server process before you ran a `mongoimport`. But as noted already, you probably should not be doing that anyway. So it looks like you might need to read some more and understand exactly what you are asking first.